# awk how to add new line after each 2wo pattern match

Tags: bash, awk, yq

I have a yml file that is automatically generated depending on the received parameters in GitLab, it can contain many triggers (structure will be the same overall file), jobs. Here is an example of his possible data:

```
name-1-${VAR1}-${VAR2}:
  stage: trigger-1
  trigger:
    project: test/test1
    branch: master
    strategy: depend
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "pipeline"'

release-build-name_1:
  extends: 
    - .build-name_1
    - .test-name_1
  image: name
  variables:
    NAME_1: "build-name_1"
    ... # mean n+1 key: values, or another structure
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 week
    paths:
      - ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/file_1.log
      ...
  rules:
    - if: $STAGE == "TEST1"
    - if: $STAGE == "TEST2"
      when: manual

name-2-${VAR1}-${VAR2}:
  stage: trigger-2
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "pipeline"'
    - if: $STAGE == "TEST1"
  trigger:
    project: test/test2
    branch: dev
    strategy: depend

name-1-${VAR3}-${VAR4}:
...
```

What I need:

1. for each trigger with a name: "^name-1-*";
2. find in it block: "rules:";
3. add the additional line: "- if: $VALUE" in that block.

I don't understand how to add a check for blank lines between patterns.

Pseudo code of what I (think) need with awk:

```
n=0
  if   /^name-1-*/      { ++n }
  elif /^\s*$/          { n=0 }
  elif n== 1 and /  rules:/   { print "    - if: $VALUE" }
```

Comment: please update the question with the expected result

Answer (score 3):

For structured data files such as YAML you should use an appropriate data processor, rather than a plain text editor. For instance, there is [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) or [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) for processing YAML.

With both of them you could just add such an array item using:

```bash
yq '.[keys | .[] | select(test("^name-1-"))].rules += [{"if": "$VALUE"}]' file.yaml
```

- You may want to add the `-i` flag to modify the file in place
- With the kislyuk/yq implementation you also may want to add the `-y` flag to output YAML again

---

Considering the updated sample input and the clarifying [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75240029/awk-how-to-add-new-line-after-each-2wo-pattern-match/75240138?noredirect=1#comment132777075_75240138), if you want to add the new rule item only to those `.rules` arrays (of matching objects) that already existed previously, provide another criterion using `has`:

```bash
(
  .[keys | .[] | select(test("^name-1-"))]
  | select(has("rules"))
)
.rules += [{"if": "$VALUE"}]
```

(This could be further simplified towards the actual [implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info) of `yq` you are using. This more verbose version is geared to work for both implementations.)

Comment: I fixed the code example, it was oversimplified  at first (to use awk only)

Comment: @RedBlack What does that mean? Do you still expect a solution in awk?

Comment: @RedBlack The way I understand your updated question imho still fits with the solution I was trying to give. The only thing I was kind of guessing is that "$VALUE" is supposed to be the literal string rather than some referenced value, but this seems to match with other occurrences of that kind in the now updated sample document. Please clarify if I have misunderstood your update.

Comment: yq code when I parse the yml file for some blocks "name-1-" adds an additional field "rule:", but it already exists. So I struggled with this. "$VALUE" - could be any GitLab "if rules" expression, with this no problem, I'm trying to add unique.

Comment: @RedBlack If I understand correctly, you want to only add a new item to the rules array (of a matching object) if the rules array already exists. I have updated my answer accordingly. Please clarify if I have misunderstood your comment.